# How to assign date automatically to a database field if the date textbox is empty?

Tags: asp.net, listview, date

I have a listview within which there is a textbox named **DateofEntry**.
Now what I want is at runtime if the user does not enter any date in that **DateofEntry** textbox then today's date must be saved in the database otherwise the date that is supplied at runtime must be saved.
How can i achieve this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TextBox tmpControl = (TextBox)ListView1.FindControl("DateOfEntry");
if (tmpControl.Text == "") {
    DateTime dateToBeSaved = DateTime.Now();
}
```

Comment: Since the textbox is inside a listview......so i am not able to access it from codebehind.

Comment: Look at this thread. I think it will help you out a lot (look at the answer too). http://forums.asp.net/t/1226031.aspx/1

Comment: Null reference exception is shown in line
if (tmpControl.Text == "") near ""

Comment: Again, look at the link, this answer was just an indication

Answer (score 0):

I would set the default date in the field as today's date during page load. Let the user to change if he wants.

```
DateTextBox.Text = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString();
```

*Ps : You may even choose the format you want..*

Comment: Since the textbox is inside a listview......so i am not able to access it from codebehind.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the JavaScript function of Date();

Like. Ex.

```
<script>
 function addD  ate(){
 date = new Date();
 var month = date.getMonth()+1;
 var day = date.getDate();
 var year = date.getFullYear();

 if (document.getElementById('date').value == ''){
   document.getElementById('date').value = day + '-' + month + '-' + year;
  }
}
 </script>
      <body onload="addDate();">
         Today's Date is: <input type="text" id="date">
      </body>
```

you got my point?

Comment: This is not best...But I just tell you this is a way to do it.

Comment: Guys you are forgetting the thing that textbox is inside listview...so i can't access it from my code behind..Can I??

Answer (score 0):

You can use as follows.

Check the textbox value on postback on click event

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(DateOfEntry.Text)) {
    DateTime dateToBeSaved = DateTime.Now();
}
else
{
   //get the value form the text box
}
```

Or you can manage it in your database.
If you are using store procedure.
Check for the dateField value
If it is null
don't Insert any value in this column.
Make the default value of your column to current date.

Comment: I have a function instead of stored procedure ........I tried to do this but incase of a function i need to send to send the date at runtime as a parameter..How can i do it??Can you please elaborate??